# Understanding promise.race() usage

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, es6-promise

As far as I know, there are two options about [**`promise`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

- [`promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)
- [`promise.race()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race)

Ok, I know what `promise.all()` does. It runs promises in parallel, and `.then` gives you the values if both resolved successfully. Here is an example:

```
Promise.all([
  $.ajax({ url: 'test1.php' }),
  $.ajax({ url: 'test2.php' })
])
.then(([res1, res2]) => {
  // Both requests resolved
})
.catch(error => {
  // Something went wrong
});
```

But I don't understand what does `promise.race()` is supposed to do exactly? In other word, what's the difference with not using it? Assume this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'test1.php',
    async: true,
    success: function (data) {
        // This request resolved
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'test2.php',
    async: true,
    success: function (data) {
        // This request resolved
    }
});
```

See? I haven't used `promise.race()` and it behaves like `promise.race()`. Anyway, is there any simple and clean example to show me when exactly should I use `promise.race()` ?

Comment: There's also `Promise.allSettled`.

Answer (score 47):

As you see, the `race()` will return the promise instance which is firstly resolved or rejected:

```js
var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
    setTimeout(resolve, 500, 'one'); 
});
var p2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
    setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'two'); 
});

Promise.race([p1, p2]).then(function(value) {
  console.log(value); // "two"
  // Both resolve, but p2 is faster
});
```

For a scenes to be used， maybe you want to limit the cost time of a request ：

```
var p = Promise.race([
    fetch('/resource-that-may-take-a-while'),
    new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
         setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('request timeout')), 5000)
    })
])
p.then(response => console.log(response))
p.catch(error => console.log(error))
```

With the `race()` you just need to get the returned promise, you needn't  care about which one of the promises in the `race([])` firstly returned,

However, without the `race`, just like your example, you need to care about which one will firstly returned, and called the callback in the both `success` callback.

Comment: However, the `fetch` method call continues, but the output will be discarded whenever it eventually returns. A timeout should instead cancel the pending request.

Comment: What difference compared to `Promise.any`?

Comment: @Dominic the difference is that `Promise.race` will be quicker, and here's why:
`Promise.race` is settled as soon as any of the promises you feed it **settle**, whether they are fulfilled or rejected.

`Promise.any` is settled as soon as any of the promises you feed it is _fulfilled_ or they are all rejected, in which case it's rejected with an AggregateError.

so in the "all rejected" scenario, `Promise.any` will be slower because it'll wait until all promises get rejected.


Not much of a difference, but still.

Answer (score 21):

I've used it for request batching. We had to batch tens of thousands of records into batches for a long running execution. We could do it in parallel, but didn't want the number of pending requests to get out of hand.

Race lets us keep a fixed number of parallel promises running and add one to replace whenever one completes

```
const _ = require('lodash')

async function batchRequests(options) {
    let query = { offset: 0, limit: options.limit };

    do {
        batch = await model.findAll(query);
        query.offset += options.limit;

        if (batch.length) {
            const promise = doLongRequestForBatch(batch).then(() => {
                // Once complete, pop this promise from our array
                // so that we know we can add another batch in its place
                _.remove(promises, p => p === promise);
            });
            promises.push(promise);

            // Once we hit our concurrency limit, wait for at least one promise to
            // resolve before continuing to batch off requests
            if (promises.length >= options.concurrentBatches) {
                await Promise.race(promises);
            }
        }
    } while (batch.length);

    // Wait for remaining batches to finish
    return Promise.all(promises);
}

batchRequests({ limit: 100, concurrentBatches: 5 });
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the only example I've found of how to manage the array of Promise values. For anyone else trying to use the code above, the `_.remove()` statement seems to use the Lodash library. Here's the code I used instead:


`for (let i = 0; i < promises.length; i++) {
        if (promises[i] === promise) {
            promises.splice(i, 1);
            break;
        }
    }`

Comment: Thanks. I've added a require to the above example so the use of lodash is clear

Answer (score 14):

It's a piece to build a timeout system, where:

1. the request/computation may be canceled by another channel
2. it will still be used later, but we need an interaction *now*.

For an example of the second, one might show a spinner "instantly" while still defaulting to show real content if it comes in fast enough. Try running the below a few times - note at least some console message comes "instantly". This might normally be attached to perform operations on a UI.

The key to note is - the result of `Promise.race` is much less important than the side effects (though, this then is a code smell).

```js
// 300 ms _feels_ "instant", and flickers are bad

function getUserInfo(user) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // had it at 1500 to be more true-to-life, but 900 is better for testing
    setTimeout(() => resolve("user data!"), Math.floor(900*Math.random()));
  });
}

function showUserInfo(user) {
  return getUserInfo().then(info => {
    console.log("user info:", info);
    return true;
  });
}

function showSpinner() {
  console.log("please wait...")
}

function timeout(delay, result) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(result), delay);
  });
}
Promise.race([showUserInfo(), timeout(300)]).then(displayed => {
  if (!displayed) showSpinner();
});
```

Inspiration credit to [a comment by captainkovalsky](https://gist.github.com/gskachkov/db7c2b95bb321c6d353d26a808a8d71d#gistcomment-2325382).

An example of the first:

```js
function timeout(delay) {
  let cancel;
  const wait = new Promise(resolve => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => resolve(false), delay);
    cancel = () => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      resolve(true);
    };
  });
  wait.cancel = cancel;
  return wait;
}


function doWork() {
  const workFactor = Math.floor(600*Math.random());
  const work = timeout(workFactor);
  
  const result = work.then(canceled => {
    if (canceled)
      console.log('Work canceled');
    else
      console.log('Work done in', workFactor, 'ms');
    return !canceled;
  });
  result.cancel = work.cancel;
  return result;
}

function attemptWork() {
  const work = doWork();
  return Promise.race([work, timeout(300)])
    .then(done => {
      if (!done)
        work.cancel();
      return (done ? 'Work complete!' : 'I gave up');
  });
}

attemptWork().then(console.log);
```

You can see from this one that the timeout's `console.log` is never executed when the timeout hits first. It should fail/succeed about half/half, for testing convenience.

Comment: Excellent examples, @Iiridayn.  About the first one, though, I am curious why you chose to treat your `timeout` as an exception wasting your `catch` block executing `setSpinner()`, instead of treating it as temporary state as in `var delayedSpinner =
    (ms) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, ms, 'please wait...')); Promise.race([showUserInfo(), delayedSpinner(300)])`.  That way, you can still properly handle exceptions from `showUserInfo` and not silently drop them, displaying your spinner forever.

Comment: @JayAllen I didn't want to bother with canceling the timeout or checking a shared state before showing the spinner. I've updated it to resolve a boolean (console.log returns `undefined` which is falsey) so you can use it in production code with fewer modifications :P.

Answer (score 8):

Here's an easy example to understand the use of `promise.race()`:

Imagine you need to fetch some data from a server and if the data takes too long to load (say 15 seconds) you want to show an error.

You would call promise.race() with two promises, the first being your ajax request and the second being a simple `setTimeout(() => resolve("ERROR"), 15000)`

Comment: why wouldn't you use a timeout setting on your network call?

Comment: @JaromandaX is right. In your example, using `timeout` in the ajax request would be better. Thank you anyway, upvote

Answer (score 7):

**Summary:**

`Promise.race` is a JS built in function that accepts an iterable of Promises (e.g. `Array`) as an argument. This function then **asynchronously** returns a Promise as soon as one in of the Promises passed in the iterable is either resolved or rejected.

**Example 1:**

```js
var promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('Promise-one'), 500);
});

var promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('Promise-two'), 100);
});

Promise.race([promise1, promise2]).then((value) => {
  console.log(value);
  // Both resolve, but promise2 is faster than promise 1
});
```

In this example first an array of Promises is passed in `Promise.race`. Both of the promises resolve but promise1 resolves faster. Therefore the promise is resolved with the value of promise1, which is the string `'Promise-one'`.

**Example 2:**

```js
const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('succes'), 2000);
});

const promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => reject('err'), 1000);
});

Promise.race([promise1, promise2])
  .then((value) => {
  console.log(value);
}).catch((value) => {
  console.log('error: ' + value);
});
```

In this second example the second promise rejects faster than the first promise can resolve. Therefore `Promise.race` will return a rejected promise with the value of `'err'` which was the value that Promise2 rejected with.

The key point to understand is that `Promice.race` takes an iterable of Promises and returns a Promise based on the first resolved or rejected promise in that iterable (with the corresponding `resolve()` or `reject()` values).

Comment: One correction on your second sentence: "This function immediately returns a Promise which is evaluated asynchronously and, once the stack is empty, yields the value of the first Promise in the iterable to resolve or reject".  It definitely evaluates all of the Promises in the iterable in parallel (asynchronously) and will not resolve/reject to a value until the iterable's stack is empty.

Comment: setTimeout(() => resolve('Promise-two'), 1000); Here the timeout should have been 100 instead of 1000 for promise two to resolve faster. Confused me for a while there

Answer (score 3):

Let's take an sample workaround of `Promise.race` like below.

```
const race = (promises) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return promises.forEach(f => f.then(resolve).catch(reject));
    })
};
```

You can see `race` function executes all promises, but whomever finishes first  will resolve/reject with wrapper `Promise`.