# React timeout race conditions

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous

```
updatePixelBuffer(x, y) {
    console.log("cleared from update", this.state.pixelRefreshTimer);
    window.clearTimeout(this.state.pixelRefreshTimer);

    let pixelRefreshTimer = window.setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("from timer", pixelRefreshTimer);
        this.triggerPixelRefresh();
    }, 3000);
    console.log("set timer", pixelRefreshTimer);

    this.setState({
        pixelRefreshTimer: pixelRefreshTimer,
    });

    // store operation in buffer and perform visual draw
}

triggerPixelRefresh() {
    console.log("cleared from refresh", this.state.pixelRefreshTimer);
    window.clearTimeout(this.state.pixelRefreshTimer);

    // update data structure with operations in buffer
}
```

**Most of the time updatePixelBuffer is called on it's own multiple times** since I'm using it to store drawing operations before I batch update them on the data structure, I'm allowing the user to visualize the drawing operations live (even though the data structure hasn't updated them yet).

My dilemma starts when I want to call triggerPixelRefresh() right after making a call to updatePixelBuffer(x, y). The timer **should not** set off after this call.

```
updatePixelBuffer(1, 2);
triggerRefresh();
```

Since setState is asynchronous, I don't know how to guarantee that window.clearTimeout in triggerPixelRefresh() will clear the newly set timer in updatePixelBuffer if they are called one after the other. I'm not sure what pattern to use to guarantee this.

updatePixelRefresh sets up a timer so that if triggerPixelRefresh is not called upon later, it will be called. It's to guarantee that the operations in the buffer are made at a later time. triggerRefresh needs to cancel that timer and immediately update the data structure with the stored operations. I need to prevent the refresh from being called upon at unpredictable times.

I technically could just directly modify the state to make them run synchronously, but I would prefer not to.

Comment: look about promises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState(state,callback)` overload exists for that: to guarantee `callback` being called after the state has been changed.

that being said, you could transform your `updatePixelBuffer` to return a `Promise` which resolves when `callback` has been called.

also, you could have your `triggerPixelRefresh` also return a promise that resolve immediately.

at the end, wrap them both in function, have function expose `triggerPixelRefreshPromise` resolve method which you can call afterwards.

in the end, wrap both promises in `Promise.race([p1,p2])`.

what `Promise.race(p1,p2)` does is that it will resolve to whichever of `p1,p2` promises resolve first (in other words, timeout or your direct call).

take a look at this also:
[Understanding promise.race() usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46376432/understanding-promise-race-usage)

Comment: I wasn't aware I could use a callback for setState. Definitely helped. I passed in a true/false parameter to determine when I should be setting timers. If I don't need to set a timer, I know for a fact I can just wipe the last timer and then triggerRefresh as a callback after setState. Helped a lot! Thanks! Definitely will consider promises in the future, but I believe I would need a babel polyfill for promises.

Answer (score 0):

It should be very relatively easy to get to what you are looking for, employ callback hooks in your operation. So instead of trying to force synchronicity by calling one function after the other (*even though this works in everyday's work it is still technically not guaranteed because the OS/Runtime/Hardware can decide to go attend some more important work before running your next function*) so I'd say rather have `triggerPixelRefresh` as a function input to `updatePixelBuffer`that way you have more control on when to call it.

```
updatePixelBuffer(x, y,triggerRefreshHandler) {
...call triggerRefresherHandler at the appropriate time here
}
```

Then you can do

```
updatePixelBuffer(1, 2,triggerRefresh);
```

It's probably not too critical, but I notice that you are using quite a lot of window object, I'm just curious if this will not cause any issues since React uses a Virtual DOM and SPA's normally will also run in server when you want server rendering performance and in an environment like NodeJS window would not exist.

Happy coding