# Promise.all Replacement?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, parallel-processing

Is there any way where I can call multiple async functions in Javascript, but get response of the call as soon as one completes, unlike Promise.all that waits for all async calls to complete? 
What I want is, run async calls in parallel, and get response of a respective call as soon as it gets completed while other calls are still running and then update the react state.

I am already using Promise.all for multiple async calls, but it gives responses when all calls are finished.

Comment: Do you still need the behavior of `Promise.all()` in addition, or no?

Comment: I think you are looking for [Promise.race](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race). To better understand Promise.race see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46376432/understanding-promise-race-usage)

Comment: What you describe is just adding the same callback to all your Promises, is it really just what you want?

Comment: I want to call async functions, and I need response of every function. But with promise.all, I get all the responses when all calls are successfully completed. What I want is that, calls go asynchronously and I keep getting response as soon as each respective call is completed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your question the phrase "than update ... state" is the key. You plan to update the state in such a way that as soon as one promise "completed" the **corresponding** state is updated. You have been trying something like this

```
async function f1(){ await Promise.resolve(); }
async funciton f2(){ await Promise.resolve(); }
async function fn(){ await Promise.resolve(); }

async function drvAsync(){
  const [r1, r2, rn] = await Promise.all([f1(), f2(), fn()]);
  u1(r1);
  u2(r2);
  un(rn);
}
```

where f[n] is an async business function, u[n] is a method to deal with the result from it. This schema is not acceptable in your scenario. Perhaps fn completes faster than others and you want to update N-th state earlier.

My recommendation is use no synchronization primitives at all. Instead you should deal with the results separately.

```
function drv(){
  f1().then((r1)=>u1(r1)).catch((e)=>er(e));
  f2().then((r2)=>u2(r2)).catch((e)=>er(e));
  fn().then((rn)=>un(rn)).catch((e)=>er(e));;  
}
```

This schema will call each update (u[n]) method without waiting results from others.

Comment: You got that right!
In my scenario, I have a list of items, whose length is not known. How can use this in my current scenario?

`items.forEach(item => {
    apiCall(item).then(.....)
})`

Will it work in parallel?

Comment: Yes, it will. First phase apiCall will start to run for each item. At second phase callbacks in **than** / **catch** will be called appropriately.

Comment: One more thing @mx.Wolf, I tried your implementation, and it is working like a charm. Now, how can I wait for all to complete whether any of it was erroneous or not?

Comment: Oh, that is another story. This time you do use Promise.all but wrap each apiCall in async ()=>{ try{await apiCall(item)} catch(e){log (e)}} or similar construct to show no sign of rejection to Promise.all

Comment: I handled it by wrapping each api call in promise. First off, updated state in "then" and then resolved or rejected promise. and added all calls in array and used promise.all to wait for all. State, respectively updates in "then" while we also wait for all calls to complete in promise.all. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can just iterate over an array of promises and change the state on each promise resolution:

```js
let state = null;

const p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve({p1: 1});
  }, 2000);
});
const p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve({p2: 2});
  }, 1000);
});
const p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve({p3: 3});
  }, 3000);
});

// Iterate promises
[p1, p2, p3].forEach(p => {
  p.then(res => {
    state = Object.assign({}, state, res);
    console.log(state);
  });
});

console.log(state);
```

You could create your own `Promise` method for this task:

```
if (!Promise.each) {
  Promise.each = function(promises, callback, error) {
    if (promises && Array.isArray(promises)) {
      promises.forEach(p => {
        p.then(res => {
          callback(res);
        }, err => {
          if (error) {
              error(err);
          } else {
              console.log(err);
          }          
        });
      });
    }
  }
}

// Usage
Promise.each([p1, p2, p3], updateState);
```

Comment: Honestly, I'd just go with `Promise.each = function each (iterable, onFulfilled, onRejected) { for (const value of iterable) this.resolve(value).then(onFulfilled, onRejected); };`.

Comment: My 2 cents: Loosing the control over the new Promises is IMM sub-optimal. You might prefer to at least return the result of mapping your input rather than a sterile forEach. This way one can do Promise.all( Promise.each( promises, doSomethingForEach ) ).then( doSomethingWhenAllDone ).

Answer (score 3):

This is what [`Promise.race`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) is for:

> The `Promise.race()` method returns a promise that fulfills or rejects as soon as one of the promises in an iterable fulfills or rejects, with the value or reason from that promise.

For instance:

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function main() {
  const promises = [
    sleep(1000).then(() => "world"),
    sleep(100).then(() => "hello"),
  ];
  const promisesWithIndices = promises.map((p, index) =>
    p.then((result) => ({result, index}))
  );
  while (promisesWithIndices.length > 0) {
    const {result, index} = await Promise.race(promisesWithIndices);
    console.log("%s -> %s", index, result);
    promisesWithIndices.splice(index, 1);
  }
}

main();  // prints "1 -> hello"; then prints "0 -> world" after a while
```

Comment: No, Promise.race only is not a solution, you'll only have one of the conditions OP is willing to have (no way from there only to also handle the resolving of next Promises).

Comment: @Kaiido: How not? You can just run `Promise.race` repeatedly, on a smaller array each time, for instance. (Added an example.)

Comment: Well you are now far from having **only** Promise.race, and the iterator you used could be used directly by moving what you have in the async `while` to a simple callback you'd have set to all your promises...

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't use async/await you can do the calls in parallel. Note that browsers have connection limit for network requests so if you execute for example 100 calls it will not be parallel but rather be queued.

You need a callback to execute when the promise resolved. If this callback is the same for all functions than just loop all calls, create the promise and resolve with the same function.

```
function resolved(data) {
    // ...
}

const promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve('Success!');
}).then(resolved);

const promise2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve('Success!');
}).then(resolved);
```